# Laravel group by date and count

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to add extra information to a Laravel eloquent collection based on the counting number of start(date) field. so the scenario is I have an "appointments" table, I want to add extra attributes to the object in the collection that's returned by eloquent if any days have more than 10 appointments. I have tried many ways like group by and count but didn't work. anyway I have the code below that's I think I'm so close to it but I have been working on it but couldn't find how to make it achieve what I want. I think I'm stuck and I can't think any more. I have commented most of the lines.

```
        $allAppointments = Appointment::get($columns); //returning all the appointments

        $days = Appointment::get()->groupBy(function ($val) {
                return Carbon::parse($val->start)->format('d');
            }); //here I'm returning appointments by group without the count

        $counter = [];

        foreach ($days as $day => $appointments) {
            foreach ($appointments as $appointment) {

                if (Carbon::parse($appointment->start)->format('d') == $day) {
                    $counter = [Carbon::parse($appointment->start)->format('d') => $day]; //here I'm trying to make an array and count the days but not working
                }
                dd($counter);
                foreach ($allAppointments as $allAppointment) {
                    if (Carbon::parse($allAppointment->start)->format('d') == $day && count($counter) == 10) //here I want to compare the dates and check if that day have more than 10 appointments
                        $allAppointment->setAttribute('backgroundColor', 'red'); //here I want to add the extra information
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange after working on it more than almost 10 hours, just 20 minutes after posting it here I could make it work. the code is below:

```
public function all()
    {
        $columns = [
            'id',
            'title',
            'start',
            'end',
            'note',
            'allDay',
            'editable',
        ];

        $allAppointments = Appointment::get($columns);
        $days = Appointment::get()
            ->groupBy(function ($val) {
                return Carbon::parse($val->start)->format('d');
            });


        foreach ($days as $day => $appointments) {
            foreach ($appointments as $appointment) {
                foreach ($allAppointments as $key => $allAppointment) {
                    if (Carbon::parse($allAppointment->start)->format('d') == $day && $appointments->count() >= 10){
                        $allAppointment->setAttribute('backgroundColor', 'red');
                    }
                }         
            }
        }

        return $allAppointments;
    }
```

Comment: Is it more efficient to do the computation in the DB query directly or to do it in PHP loops like you did? Is the difference important?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    Appointment::select(DB::raw('if(count(*) > 10, true, false) as more_than_ten_appointment'))->groupBy(function ($val) {
            return Carbon::parse($val->start)->format('d');
        })->get();
```

if DB class isn't exist add after namespace:

```
use DB;
```

Comment: Thank you I found the solution, I added it

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
        $allAppointments = Appointment::get($columns); //returning all the appointments

        $days = Appointment::get()->groupBy(function ($val) {
            return Carbon::parse($val->start)->format('d');
        }); //returning appointments by group without the count

        foreach ($days as $day => $appointments) {
            foreach ($appointments as $appointment) {
                $counter = 0;
                if (Carbon::parse($appointment->start)->format('d') == $day) {
                    $counter = count($appointments); //appointments counter
                }
                foreach ($allAppointments as $allAppointment) {
                    if (Carbon::parse($allAppointment->start)->format('d') == $day && $counter >= 10) //compare the date and check if that day have more than 10 appointments
                        $allAppointment->setAttribute('backgroundColor', 'red'); //add the extra information here
                }
            }
        }
```